# Basic questions around Activiti BPMN

Tags: java, spring-mvc, activiti, bpmn

I am new to activiti activiti.org ...

My requirements are:

- I need a web designer for the user to create workflows at runtime through web.
- The tasks of the workflow are custom i.e I need to somehow extend the activiti designer to include my tasks.
- I also want to remove unncessary tasks from the web ui.

Can I do all of this via activiti free version? If yes, please point me to the documentation for the above three.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I've worked for a company where I had to work in the creation of a BPMN designer, it's a huge effort, so you should consider to use something like this:

http://bpmn.io/

http://demo.bpmn.io/

It's one of the best designers you can find out there, you can embed it in your own app, it's Javascript so if you want to create custom activities, going through the code, you will be able to add them to the toolbar and extend the functionality, it has actually a very flexible API for it.

Regarding to the Activiti engine, this designer will give you the XML ready for the execution on Activiti.

As a side note, bpmn.io is a project from guys who worked for Activiti and they created a fork of that project, the result is `Camunda`, so you can trust it has been done by people who know the field.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your initial question, the community edition of Activiti, particularly Version 6 is very capable of handling what you are after, including the customizations of the task palette.

I am also a big fan of bpmn.io like the other poster, however, bpmn.io is packaged as an "electron" application (node.js) and as such must be modified to run as a web application. Also, the level of effort to customize the palette is likely higher than using the Activiti V6 modeler. I say this having customized both bpmn.io and the activiti modelers.

Either way, both would work for you.
Hope this helps,
Greg

Comment: the Activiti V6 modeler - is it a web modeler?

Comment: Yes, the V6 modeler is web based.